# Facebook insights return empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I ll try to explain what I want to do step by step.

- I have a web page which post some things to facebook using his API. I have the next permissions:

  ```
          Permission.USER_PHOTOS,
          Permission.EMAIL,
          Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION,

          Permission.READ_INSIGHTS,
          Permission.USER_BIRTHDAY,
          Permission.USER_POSTS,
          Permission.USER_LIKES
  ```

The user accepts these permissions at the facebook login. I post some info to facebook, the post is shared successfully, and I get the postID.

Then, I want to get the insights. Before coding, I am testing this on the facebook developer console. Can you please, tell me if I am miss doing something?

- I choose the app [image: App selection]
- When I want to create the token, which is the right option? User Access Token, App Token or Page Token?
  [image: Token selection]

I get this result for the user access token[image][image]

With the apptoken [image]

and the fb_traceid value is this: [image]

And this is not a page, then I can't try with the last option.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you posting to, a user or a page timeline?

Comment: @CBroe I am posting to a user with this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

Comment: There are no insights for posts on user timelines.

Comment: @CBroe Then, can you please tell me how to do it? Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Please give a ad account for this as the app give its id for getting the insight